# How to use let bindings conditionally in Clojure

Tags: if-statement, clojure, let

I'm new to Clojure and trying to concisely write a recursive function to merge two sorted sequences into a new sorted sequence.

This is my attempt, which doesn't compile:

```
(defn seq-merge [a-seq b-seq]
  (cond
    (empty? a-seq) b-seq
    (empty? b-seq) a-seq
    :else (let (if (< (first a-seq) (first b-seq))
                 [f (first a-seq) r (rest a-seq) h b-seq]
                 [f (first b-seq) r (rest b-seq) h a-seq])
            (cons f (seq-merge r h)))))
```

Initially, I wanted something like:

```
(if condition
  (let [...] 
  (let [...]
    (code-that-uses-conditional-bindings))
```

But it seemed that each 'let' needed to be directly followed by the code so this didn't work.

The aim is to not have to repeat the `(cons f (seq-merge r h))` line twice if it can be avoided.

My current solution is this:

```
(defn seq-merge [a-seq b-seq]
  (cond
    (empty? a-seq) b-seq
    (empty? b-seq) a-seq
    :else (let [a-low? (< (first a-seq) (first b-seq))
                f (if a-low? (first a-seq) (first b-seq))
                r (if a-low? (rest a-seq) (rest b-seq))
                h (if a-low? b-seq a-seq)]
            (cons f (seq-merge r h)))))
```

But this seems much clunkier by having an 'if' for every binding value.

Comment: Check out https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let and https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when-let

Comment: @marco.m I don't think these help here, marco. If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1831), there is no binding if the expression-to-be-bound is false.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring). In this case it doesn't do wonders, but it is arguably a bit cleaner.

```
(defn seq-merge [a-seq b-seq]
  (cond
    (empty? a-seq) b-seq
    (empty? b-seq) a-seq
    :else (let [[f r h] (if (< (first a-seq) (first b-seq))
                          [(first a-seq) (rest a-seq) b-seq]
                          [(first b-seq) (rest b-seq) a-seq])]
            (cons f (seq-merge r h)))))
```

With a very simple change you can also make it lazy. That way it won't overflow the stack and it'll work with infinite lists.

```
(defn seq-merge [a-seq b-seq]
  (lazy-seq
   (cond
     (empty? a-seq) b-seq
     (empty? b-seq) a-seq
     :else (let [[f r h] (if (< (first a-seq) (first b-seq))
                           [(first a-seq) (rest a-seq) b-seq]
                           [(first b-seq) (rest b-seq) a-seq])]
             (cons f (seq-merge r h))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using destructuring in the function arguments and in the let you can clean it up a little:

```
(defn seq-merge [[a & as :as a-seq] [b & bs :as b-seq]]
  (cond
    (empty? a-seq) b-seq
    (empty? b-seq) a-seq
    :else (let [[f r h]
                (if (< a b) [a as b-seq] [b bs a-seq])]
            (cons f (seq-merge r h)))))
```